# How to obtain the current number of jiffies since reboot in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

Linux's `/proc/PID/stat` lists several metrics that are measured in jiffies.  Is there a way to get the *current* # of jiffies since reboot?  Jiffies I also assume to be seconds times the USER_HZ value.

Can I get this by summing the first 4 arguments on the `cpu` line in `/proc/stat`?

---

**UPDATE**:

```
$ date +"%s.%N" && grep '^jiffies' timer_list
1262103103.162169230
jiffies: 1007865965
jiffies: 1007865965
jiffies: 1007865965
jiffies: 1007865965
$ date +"%s.%N" && grep '^jiffies' timer_list
1262103108.706475051
jiffies: 1007867351
jiffies: 1007867351
jiffies: 1007867351
jiffies: 1007867351
```

The delta between these is almost exactly 250 jiffies / second.  Appears as though all the jiffies lines per CPU are equivalent (though I guess they might not be if a hot | ondemand CPU was provisioned/replaced).  I think this gives me the best place to pull a consistent jiffies counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically jiffy in computer parlance is the duration of 1 tick of the system timer interrupt.  It's not absolute though.  For Linux 2.6.13+ on Intel x86 jiffy is 4ms, but can range from 1ms to 10ms depending upon architecture and kernel version.

From the [Kernel Timer Systems](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Timer_Systems) page:

> Historically, the kernel used 100 as the value for HZ, yielding a jiffy interval of 10 ms. With 2.4, the HZ value for i386 was changed to 1000, yeilding a jiffy interval of 1 ms. Recently (2.6.13) the kernel changed HZ for i386 to 250. (1000 was deemed too high).

It lists `/proc/timer_list` and `/proc/timer_stats`.

You can activate the timer_stats at boot time, then cat this file to print stats.

Comment: How does one activate the timer_stats?  Correct, the 'jiffies' is an arbitrary increment in this case as long as the various `/proc/PID/stat` files report a metric that is equivalent to some total I can use to calculate relative %s.  OK, so there is a "jiffies" line in `/proc/timer_list`, I'll update original post.

Comment: To start collection of stats "echo 1 > /proc/timer_stats", which you can put at the start of your init cycle.

Answer (score 4):

No, you only need the first line. The first line aggregates everything else in the other cpu lines.

Example output:

```
[john@awesome]$cat /proc/stat
cpu  35024984 1771325 94153391 1810948613 2648063 352387 557232
cpu0 13955475 927654 59431476 895791946 1910028 318618 438048
cpu1 21069509 843671 34721915 915156667 738035 33769 119184
intr 1403502159 1138402452 597 0 3 3 0 5 0 1 0 0 0 12315 0 92119425 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 57676632 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 115290726 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ctxt 21043582666
btime 1252332786
processes 25663823
procs_running 1
procs_blocked 0
```

What each column means (left to right):

- user: normal processes executing in user mode
- nice: niced processes executing in user mode
- system: processes executing in kernel mode
- idle: idle time
- iowait: waiting for I/O to complete
- irq: servicing interrupts
- softirq: servicing softirqs

as you can see, the first column after cpu (user mode processes) is equal to the 2 numbers beneath it added together.

Comment: Is this not only for user time for which the cpu was scheduled?  The others being nice, system & idle?

Comment: added the meaning of each column.

Comment: Right, but to find the total # of jiffies since start, would one not do something like `awk '/^cpu/{print $2+$3+$4+$5}' /proc/stat`?

Comment: You only want user,nice,system and idle? You can do `awk '/^cpu\>/{print $2+$3+$4+$5}' /proc/stat`

Comment: Appears as though any given time delta is not consistent with a sum across the `/proc/stat`!

Answer (score 4):

In later Linux Kernels you can query `/proc/timer_list` and find out the number of jiffies since reboot from each CPU that's present within the system. They should always match.

```
$ grep -E "^cpu|^jiff" /proc/timer_list
cpu: 0
jiffies: 4299690231
cpu: 1
jiffies: 4299690231
```

If you take a look at the code behind [`timer_list.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/time/timer_list.c) the bit that prints the above:

```
...
...
        P_ns(iowait_sleeptime);
        P(last_jiffies);
        P(next_timer);
        P_ns(idle_expires);
        SEQ_printf(m, "jiffies: %Lu\n",
               (unsigned long long)jiffies);
```

Notice that it's `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1):

jiffies per second:

```
awk 'BEGIN {"cat /proc/timer_list | grep '\''^jiffies'\'' | awk '\''{print $2}'\''" | getline a; "cat /proc/uptime | awk '\''{print $1}'\''" | getline b ;printf "%.4f\n", a/b}'
```

Explanation: It divides jiffies since boot found in /proc/timer_list by the seconds since boot found in /proc/uptime

Comment: I get `75409.1301` so that does not seem stable in general case. `uname -a` reports `Linux semyol-329-b 3.19.0-33-lowlatency #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 6 19:30:45 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.